# Custom Post Type as invoice or order template

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

On homepage I would like to insert form that collects client details and saves it to wordpress backend.

I was thinking to use custom_post_type

```
register_post_type('invoices',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Invoices'),
                'singular_name' => __('Invoice')
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'supports' => array('title')
        )
    );
```

1. How I remove ability to publish? and view post / slug forms? This invoices won't be published on homepage. So is there a way to make `post_type` private? I thought `'public' => false` would do the trick, but this hides from dashboard.
2. I would like to add fields, like name/email/type of service. Is the only way to do this by adding add_meta_box?
3. How do I pass data from unauthenticated visitor on homepage to wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To hide it from front, use following configuration in your register_post_type args

```
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'publicly_queryable' => false,
'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
```

2) If you look for a smoother approach, i would recommend using [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/)

3) You can set up custom form and use [wp_insert_post()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post)